# Prove: if $a > 1$, the sequence $\frac{n}{a^{n}}$ is monotone for $n$ large.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

The book I am using for my Advance Calculus course is Introduction to Analysis by Arthur Mattuck.

Prove: if $a > 1$, the sequence $\frac{n}{a^{n}}$ is monotone for $n$ large.

This is my rough proof to this question. I was wondering if anybody can look over it and see if I made a mistake or if there is a simpler way of doing this problem. I want to thank you ahead of time it is greatly appreciated.So lets begin:

[image]

Comment: When $a=2$, $n_1=1$, and $n_2=2$, we get: $n_1/a^{n_1}=1/2=2/4=n_2/a^{n_2}$. In your solution you only have strict inequalities everywhere, so something is wrong. My guess is that I'm not entirely sure why the second implication should hold. You may want some lower limit for $n_1$. Remember the keywords "for $n$ large".

Answer (score 2):

The argument given in the post does not work. For one thing the first implication is not correct.

Let $b_n=\frac{n}{a^n}$. We will show that if $n$ is large enough, then $b_{n+1}\lt b_n$, or equivalently $\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}\lt 1$.  Note that
$$\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}=\frac{(n+1)/a^{n+1}}{n/a^n}=\frac{n+1}{n}\cdot \frac{1}{a}.$$
We have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+1}{n}=1$, and therefore there is an integer $N$ such that if $n\gt N$ then $\frac{n+1}{n}\lt \frac{1+a}{2}$.  It follows that if $n\gt N$ then
$$\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}\lt \frac{1+a}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{a}\lt 1.$$

Answer (score 0):

The proof is wrong, $n_1<n_2$ and $a^{n_1}<a^{n_2}$ does not lead to $\frac{a^{n_1}}{n_1}<\frac{a^{n_2}}{n_2}$.

In fact $\frac{a^n}{n}$ may not decreasing when n is small. take $a=1.5$ and $n=1,2$ for example.

The key is to prove for any $a>1$, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{n}{a^n}$ is decreasing when $n\ge N$

Hint: consider $\frac{n+1}{a^{n+1}}/\frac{n}{a^n}$